# admin_enqueue_scripts not load script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin to load my JS code on admin pages. In __construct in my class I use:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'zhngroup_enqueue_scripts'));
```

And this is my zhngrupa_enqueue_scripts method:

```
     public function zhngrupa_enqueue_scripts() {
         // Get order iD
         $order_id = $this->order_id;

         // If the order ID is still 0, please complete the process
         if ($order_id === 0) {
             return;
         }

         wp_register_script( 'zhngrupa-script', 'https://smiel.pl/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/zhngrupa_send_message_button_script.js', array('jquery'), true, true );
         // Add JavaScript directly in your PHP code
         wp_enqueue_script( 'zhngroup-script' );

         // Pass data to JavaScript
         wp_localize_script('zhngroup-script', 'zhngroupScriptParams', array(
             'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('zhngrupa_expired_service_nonce'),
             'order_id' => $order_id,
         ));

     }
```

Unfortunately in my code my JS file is not loaded. Strangely enough, on the test version of Wordpress, not the production version, my entire project works without any problems. Please help.

I checked through an external plugin and my method is actually connected to the admin_enqueue_scripts hook

I tried to debug the code, tested it on a local WordPress instance with the same version as in production. On the trial version, everything works without any problems.

Unfortunately, no results. My JS code is not loading into the page at all. I checked it in the page code preview.

Comment: "my code my JS file is not loaded" - do you mean not enqueued, or it is but there's a 404 or similar error in the console? Are you certain that `$order_id !== 0`?

Comment: You probably need to hard reload on the admin so the new script loads. Alternatively and if it makes sense for your use case hook it in `admin_init`.

Comment: Also on the `wp_register` you need to replace the second argument with `wp_upload_dir() . '2023/06/zhngrupa_send_message_button_script.js'` and fourth argument replace `true` with a version ex: `1.0.0`

Comment: "my code my JS file is not loaded" - do you mean not enqueued, or it is but there's a 404 or similar error in the console? --- I mean script is not enqueed. I do not have any 404 errors in console.